# VueJs temperature validation

Tags: forms, validation, vue.js, input, vuetify.js

I have this text-field and i want to validate so that the temperature is between 35 and 38 degrees, with only one digit after the comma. How can i set that range?

```
<v-text-field
                      type="number"
                      v-model="temperature"
                      name="temperature"
                      required
                      min="35"
                      max="38"
                      step=".1"
                      label=""
                      suffix="°"
                      outlined
                      dense
              ></v-text-field>
```

Comment: And what is your question/problem? Please edit your question.

Comment: Have a look at Vuelidate or VeeValidate libraries